# php fread file function

Tags: php, file

I wrote the below code to output the contents of a file twice. But it only did it once. Why is that?

The text file contents are as follows:

```
My name is Sam. Sam I am.
My name is Chris and Chris I am.
The brown fox jumped over the fence.
```

The code is as follows:

```
<?php
$file = "files/info.txt";
$handle = fopen($file, "rb");
echo fread($handle, filesize($file));
echo fread($handle, filesize($file));
?>
```

The output:

```
"My name is Sam. Sam I am. My name is Chris and Chris I am. The brown fox jumped over the fence."
```

Comment: I think you need to open file again for next attempt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Invoking fread() "uses up" the file and in order to fread() it again you have to move the reading pointer back to the beginning of the file using rewind($handle)

Comment: If you really need to echo the contents twice, probably better to assign the return from the first fread() to a variable and echo the variable twice. More efficient than reading the contents each time.

Answer (score 1):

For the first **fread()**, file pointer moves to end of the file, so second time nothing printed.
execute the bellow code , you will come to know.

```
<?php
$file = "info.txt";
$handle = fopen($file, "rb");
echo fread($handle, filesize($file)-10);
print "-----";
echo fread($handle, filesize($file));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you already read the entire contents with that handle. The handle is a pointer to the document. If you were to read just the first bytes of the file (say the first 10 bytes) like this.

```
fread($handle, 10);
```

Then the next time you call fread(), it will start where you left off.

In your example, the first time you call fread() you use the filesize, which leaves your pointer pointing at the end of the file. The next you call fread, there is nothing left to return, therefore your "echo" echo's nothing back.

Hope this helps, look at fread() and other file handling functions in php docs for more explanation at php.net